# Gradient updates for word2Vec window

Tags: self-study, word2vec

I am trying to work through the [first problem set](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/assignment1/assignment1.pdf) of Stanfords Online course CS224, and Im having trouble with question 3(e) and getting the correct vectors for a given center word, hoping to find how my code differs from the formulas.

The formula for updating each window can be shown as follows:

[image]

The functions that correspond to the cost using the softmax function is as follows:

With the softmax function itself defined as
$ Y_o(o | c) = \frac{e^{(U_o \cdot v_c)}}{\sum_{j=1}^N e^{(U_j \cdot v_c)}} $

Where c is the predicted word, $ U_i$ corresponds to the outside vector corresponding to a particular word index.

The cost is given by the cross-entropy function: - $ {\sum_{i=1} y_ilog(\hat{y_i})} $

$\delta{V_c}$ = ${U^T}\cdot(\hat{y} - y)$

$\delta{U}$ = $v_c\cdot(\hat{y} - y)^T$

Here is the code for the softmax, and skip-gram models below in Python. `predicted` -> $v_c$, `target` -> index of a given outputVectors. The `outputVectors` is the overall U matrix of all the outside word vectors.

```
def softmaxCostAndGradient(predicted, target, outputVectors):
    y_hat = softmax(outputVectors.dot(predicted.T))

    y = np.zeros(outputVectors.shape[0])
    y[target] = 1

    cost = -1*y.dot(np.log(y_hat))
    d1 = y_hat - y

    gradPred = outputVectors.T.dot(d1)
    grad = d1.reshape(d1.shape[0],1).dot(predicted.reshape(1, predicted.shape[0]))
    return cost, gradPred, grad
```

Here is my code for the skip-gram model. The tokens is a dictionary that will take in a given word, and spit out the index that correspond to that given token within the inputVectors and outputVectors.

```
def skipgram(currentWord, C, contextWords, tokens, inputVectors, outputVectors,  word2vecCostAndGradient = softmaxCostAndGradient):
    predicted = inputVectors[tokens[currentWord],:]
    target_indecies = np.vectorize(tokens.get)(contextWords)
    cost = 0
    gradIn = np.zeros(inputVectors.shape)
    gradOut = np.zeros(outputVectors.shape)

    for index in target_indecies:
        w_cost, gradPred, grad = word2vecCostAndGradient(predicted, index, outputVectors, dataset)
        cost += w_cost
        gradIn = gradIn + gradPred
        gradOut = gradOut + grad
    cost = (1/target_indecies.size)*cost

return cost, gradIn, gradOut
```